# Calc limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My HW is
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1\cdot x+2\cdot x^2+3\cdot x^3+\dots+n\cdot x^n}{n\cdot x^{n+1}}$$ as $$x\gt1$$

I've multiplied both numerator and denominator by $$1/x^n$$
so my answer $$1/x$$ 
I was told that it is not correct.
Can anybody please help?

Comment: Why would your approach be correct ? Can you justify how it would reduce to $1/x$ ?

Comment: If you multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $(x-1)^2$, you may notice a remarkable cancellation in the numerator.

Comment: Recommended that you do not say "my HW is..."

Comment: multiplying numerator by $$1/x^n$$ i get a series when each member looks like $$1/x^(n - someNumberSmallerThanN)$$ assuming x >0 its lim is = to 0.

Comment: @Alex I get $(1/x)\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac{n-1}{nx}+\frac{n-2}{nx^2}+\dots$ whereupon the limit is still not so straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1\cdot x+2\cdot x^2+3\cdot x^3+\dots+n\cdot x^n}{n\cdot x^{n+1}}$$ as $$x\gt1$$
Here it is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, let us use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

If I differentiate $n$-times (the least surviving order) and then take $n->\infty $, will solve it.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Big(\dfrac{n\cdot n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\dots1}{n\cdot(n+1)\cdot n\cdot(n-1)\dots 1\cdot x^{1}} = \dfrac{1}{(n+1)x} \Big) \rightarrow 0 $$

Comment: Use `\times` or `\cdot` for multiplication please.  `\dots` for the $...$ effect.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you, done.

Comment: Always welcomed to share the LaTeX tricks

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the numerator as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} x^j = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^{n-i}-1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{x-1}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right).
$$
It follows that the limit is equal to
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{nx^{n+1}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{n(n+1)}{2(x-1)}\right).
$$
Both summands tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the geometric sum?

$$1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Differentiate both sides and you'll get

$$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots+nx^{n-1}=\frac d{dx}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Then multiply both sides by $x$.

$$1x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots+nx^n=x\left(\frac d{dx}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)$$

then the rest is some algebra and cancellation.

Comment: If I am not misunderstood(correct me if I am). This Geometric sum works (or converges) for _x<1_, but in OP _x>1_

Comment: @L.K. You mistake for the geometric series, which is the infinite version.  We work with the finite version here.

Comment: @L.K. Surely you agree $1+2=\frac{1-4}{1-2}$?

Comment: You are right, I was thinking about this but got confused with the infinite version. This is always right, I remember now my high school days. Thank you again.

Comment: @L.K. No problem.  Also reminds me that the limit invites us to think in the infinite version, but then that is no longer the workings of the limit.